# Crossfilter data with varying shape

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have just started using crossfilter. I have little experience with data.

My data looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {_id: 001, a: 10, b: 11, c:  12},
  {_id: 002, a: 11,        c:  13},
  {_id: 003,        b: 12, c:  14},
  {_id: 004,        f: 102       },  
  {_id: 005, e:100, f:101, g: 102}
];
```

As you can see, not every object has the same or common keys. I am getting incorrect values for

```
dimension.top(), dimension.bottom()
```

For example:

```
const by_a = cf.dimension(function(d){return d.a};
const max_a = by_a.top(1)[0];
// Should be max_a =  { _id: 002, a: 11, c:  13}
// Instead returns wrong object,

const by_f = cf.dimension(function(d){return d.f};
const min_f = by_f.bottom(1)[0];
// Should be min_f = { _id: 004, e:100, f:101, g: 102}
// Wrong object again.
```

I read the [Crossfilter Gotchas](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas) but am unable to understand if any of that applies to this, or whether such a case has a solution at all. I also did not come across a similar question. I would like to be able to run basic crossfilter queries. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is precisely one of the gotchas. If you try to read a field in JavaScript and it's not there, the default value is `undefined`.

Then if you compare that to a number, it will coerce to `NaN`.

And `NaN` always compares false, which screws up sorting algorithms.

If you define your key function like this, you should get the desired (or at least predictable) behavior:

```
const by_a = cf.dimension(function(d){return d.a || 0; };
```

Or if you want them always at the bottom, even in the presence of negative numbers:

```
const by_a = cf.dimension(function(d){return d.a || -Infinity; };
```

I added an example to the "natural ordering" gotcha.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and including it in the gotcha. I am sharing the results in an answer if it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my results following Gordon's advice. Consider the following dataset :

```
const data = [
  {_id: "001", a: 10, b: 11, c:  12},
  {_id: "002", a: 11,        c:  13},
  {_id: "003", a:-11,        c:  13},
  {_id: "004", a:  0,        c:  13},
  {_id: "005",        b: 12, c:  14},
  {_id: "006",        f: 102       },  
  {_id: "007", e:100, f: 101,g: 102}
];
```

Using a callback that returns a default value of zero if a field is missing :

```
// Where dim is the field I'm dimensioning the data by
const by_dim = cf.dimension( d => d.dim || 0 ); 

// Logging the results of by_a.top(7)
0:{_id: "002", a: 11, c: 13} // Correct
1:{_id: "001", a: 10, b: 11, c: 12} //Correct
2:{_id: "007", e: 100, f: 101, g: 102} //Incorrect
3:{_id: "006", f: 102}
4:{_id: "005", b: 12, c: 14}
5:{_id: "004", a: 0, c: 13} //Should have been at index 2
6:{_id: "003", a: -11, c: 13} // Should have been at index 3

// Logging the results of  by_a.bottom(7)
0:{_id: "003", a: -11, c: 13} // Correct
1:{_id: "004", a: 0, c: 13} // Correct
2:{_id: "005", b: 12, c: 14} // Incorrect
3:{_id: "006", f: 102} 
4:{_id: "007", e: 100, f: 101, g: 102}
5:{_id: "001", a: 10, b: 11, c: 12} //Should have been at index 2
6:{_id: "002", a: 11, c: 13} //Should have been at index 3 ..
```

It seems like returning `0` in dimensioning callback when a field is missing, places those objects *between objects containing that field with value* `>0`,  and `=< 0`. But this works great for me because I can just filter out the objects with do not contain the dimension in question using Lodash or some other library.

Thanks.

Comment: That's what I'd expect, it's sorting them as zero. If you want them absolutely at the bottom you could use `-Infinity` instead - added that to my answer.

Comment: @Gordon is it possible to have a crossfilter feature that filters out the records with missing fields from the query result ? That way `dimension.top(n)` would always return the correct array ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Because then you would have different dimensions with different records and nothing would add up. Better to put those records in a bin with a special key like negative infinity. You don't have to display all the bins.